# how to make when button click event in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I want to make a page that the user put any word on textbox and returns all books with that word in (books is in mysql and i am gone to convert the query in xmlconvert.php)

```
<form id="keyword" >
    <input type="text" name="value" id="book"/>
    <br/>
    <button  onclick="showhint(functionvalue())">Search By Title</button>
</form>
```

there is the a function to get the word that user put and send it to ajax showhint();

```
<script>
    function functionvalue() {
        var bookname = document.getElementById('book').value;
        return bookname;
    }
</script>
```

there is the ajax code that get the responsetext from xmlconvert.php file where I got the q where is the word that user put and make a query with that word and return the books in xml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showhint(str) {
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

        ajax.onreadystatechange = function {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("keyword").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            }
        };

        xhttp.open("GET","xmlconvert.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();                  
    }
 </script>
```

I don't know if my thought is correct let me know if I can do that and how is possible to make it. 
Sorry my English is not so good

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning your new XMLHttpRequest to the variable ajax but then calling its commands with other names. If you named it ajax, you need to do ajax.readyState, ajax.status, ajax.open, ajax.send, etc.

So this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function showhint(str){
            var ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
                ajax.onreadystatechange=function{
                    if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
                         document.getElementById("keyword").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                    }
                 };
            ajax.open("GET","xmlconvert.php?q="+str,true);
            ajax.send();

        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to make the following changes:

1. ajax.onreadystatechange should be a function definition so include () after the function keyword
2. XMLHttpRequest should be referenced through ajax var.

So the correct code would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showhint(str) {
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

        ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("keyword").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            }
        };

        ajax.open("GET","xmlconvert.php?q="+str,true);
        ajax.send();                  
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: you have right but didnt work as i do it can you tell me if is right the query that i do in php for mysql $a=$_GET["q"]; $sql="select * from book where title=$q;"; to find the title of book that give me

Comment: can you try $sql="select * from book where title='$q';"